# How to properly remove kernel modules for RTL88x2BU in Ubuntu MATE 19.04

Tags: kernel, 19.04, realtek-wireless, dkms

I have installed Realtek RTL88x2BU drivers from [Cilynx's GitHub repo](https://github.com/cilynx/rtl88x2bu) using DKMS installation in Ubuntu MATE 19.04 with kernel 5.3.4 (and later 5.3.7)

Drivers worked fine for a week, then suddenly stopped detecting TP-Link Archer T3U AC1300 Wireless USB Adapter altogether. The same adapter works fine with other PC.

```
This is how drivers were installed:

cd rtl88x2bu
VER=$(sed -n 's/\PACKAGE_VERSION="\(.*\)"/\1/p' dkms.conf)
sudo rsync -rvhP ./ /usr/src/rtl88x2bu-${VER}
sudo dkms add -m rtl88x2bu -v ${VER}
sudo dkms build -m rtl88x2bu -v ${VER}
sudo dkms install -m rtl88x2bu -v ${VER}
sudo modprobe 88x2bu
```

So how could I completely remove kernel modules of all the previous versions (1.1, 5.6.1, etc) for RTL88x2BU? Many thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do the reverse steps:

1. Unload module

   ```
   sudo modprobe -r 8822bu
   sudo modprobe -r rtl88x2bu
   ```
2. Check for all module builds status

   ```
   sudo dkms status
   ```

   output

   > ```
   > 8822bu, 1.1: added
   > rtl88x2bu, 5.6.1, 5.2.21-050221-generic, x86_64: installed
   > rtl88x2bu, 5.6.1, 5.3.7-050307-generic, x86_64: installed
   > ```
3. Unregister it from DKMS, `sudo dkms uninstall ..` is optional as we are looking for complete purge.

   ```
   sudo dkms remove -m 8822bu/1.1
   sudo dkms remove -m rtl88x2bu/5.6.1 -k 5.2.21-050221-generic
   sudo dkms remove -m rtl88x2bu/5.6.1 -k 5.3.7-050307-generic
   ```
4. Remove source from DKMS

   ```
   cd /usr/src/
   ```

   **WARNING: Be careful `rm -r` is a dangerous command!**

   ```
   sudo rm -r rtl88x2bu-*
   ```

Comment: Ok, everything went just fine, as you described, and I was able to reinstall the drivers from the same GitHub repo. EXCEPT I'm getting these errors while trying to remove modules from previous installation from a different repo:  `sudo dkms remove -m 8822bu/1.1 | Error! Invalid number of parameters passed` and `sudo dkms uninstall 8822bu/1.1 | Error! Could not locate dkms.conf file | File: /var/lib/dkms/8822bu/1.1/source/dkms.conf does not exist`

Comment: Now if I can't remove `8822bu/1.1` (please note: there's no 'x'), that's alright. Because (1) wireless is working just fine with RTL88x2BU from Cilynx, and (2) in a week or two, I'm gonna go for a clean installation of Ubuntu MATE 19.10 anyway. Thank you so much :)

Comment: @Jags, if you want a clean remove for `8822bu` , try put back its source code in  `/usr/src/` . For module naming with 'x' , I don't have currently a running Ubuntu to check, I am will be thankful if you could edit my answer to correct it .