# RTL88x2bu Driver for new Kernel Version

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless

Just yesterday, I installed [Cilynx Driver](https://github.com/cilynx/rtl88x2bu) for my new *tp-link Archer TU3 Plus (AC1300)* and it worked just fine. (I used `lsusb` to determine my Adapters USB ID, which is `2357:0138` and the internet said it is an RTL88x2bu chipset.)

Today I did a release upgrade, and had no connection afterwards. I then tried to used an [answer on how to remove the driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1182236) and tried to reinstall the driver, but it failed.
Error when trying to remove old driver:

Error occurring during the reinstallation:

```
user@t:~/Downloads/rtl88x2bu$ sudo dkms build -m rtl88x2bu -v ${VER}

Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...

Building module:
cleaning build area...
make -j4 KERNELRELEASE=5.8.0-26-generic KVER=5.8.0-26-generic src=/usr/src/rtl88x2bu-5.6.1...(bad exit status: 2)
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.8.0-26-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl88x2bu/5.6.1/build/make.log for more information.
```

I also tried [this way](https://askubuntu.com/a/1256329/1070464), but again I get an error:

```
user@t:~/Downloads/rtl88x2bu$ make
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/5.8.0-26-generic/build M=/home/user/Downloads/rtl88x2bu  modules
make[1]: Verzeichnis „/usr/src/linux-headers-5.8.0-26-generic“ wird betreten
  CC [M]  /home/user/Downloads/rtl88x2bu/core/rtw_cmd.o
In file included from /home/user/Downloads/rtl88x2bu/include/drv_types.h:79,
                 from /home/user/Downloads/rtl88x2bu/core/rtw_cmd.c:17:
/home/user/Downloads/rtl88x2bu/include/rtw_security.h:252:8: error: redefinition of ‘struct sha256_state’
  252 | struct sha256_state {
      |        ^~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ./include/linux/filter.h:23,
                 from ./include/net/sock.h:59,
                 from ./include/linux/tcp.h:19,
                 from ./include/linux/ipv6.h:88,
                 from ./include/net/addrconf.h:50,
                 from /home/user/Downloads/rtl88x2bu/include/osdep_service_linux.h:48,
                 from /home/user/Downloads/rtl88x2bu/include/osdep_service.h:50,
                 from /home/user/Downloads/rtl88x2bu/include/drv_types.h:27,
                 from /home/user/Downloads/rtl88x2bu/core/rtw_cmd.c:17:
./include/crypto/sha.h:84:8: note: originally defined here
   84 | struct sha256_state {
      |        ^~~~~~~~~~~~
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:290: /home/user/Downloads/rtl88x2bu/core/rtw_cmd.o] Fehler 1
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1780: /home/user/Downloads/rtl88x2bu] Fehler 2
make[1]: Verzeichnis „/usr/src/linux-headers-5.8.0-26-generic“ wird verlassen
make: *** [Makefile:2284: modules] Fehler 2
```

Pleas help me to get the driver running again!

Comment: `sudo dkms install rtl88x2bu/5.6.1` and reboot

Comment: Try `sudo dkms remove -m rtl88x2bu -v 5.6.1 --all`  this  is a attempt to remove the driver from dkms tree.

Comment: @nobody thanks, the removing worked. But I still cannot reinstall. I've updated the upper code block with the new error I got

Comment: maybe kernel ist to new.  I have no knowledge about this. I would try https://github.com/RinCat/RTL88x2BU-Linux-Driver#readme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please verify that you have removed all other instances of the driver:

```
sudo dkms status
```

Next, do:

```
git clone "https://github.com/RinCat/RTL88x2BU-Linux-Driver.git" /usr/src/rtl88x2bu-git
sudo sed -i 's/PACKAGE_VERSION="@PKGVER@"/PACKAGE_VERSION="git"/g' /usr/src/rtl88x2bu-git/dkms.conf
sudo dkms add -m rtl88x2bu -v git
sudo dkms autoinstall
```

Reboot.

Comment: Thanks a lot @chili555, it worked!
I guess I'll have to do this after every Kernel update? Can I use the same code the next time, or do I first have to remove something?

Comment: @lumiemp It should work after kernel updates since dkms is used.   What is up with all these strange dkms instructions?  The sudo dkms add command should copy the source code to /usr/src

Comment: @Jeremy31 I simply copied and pasted RinCat's instructions from his README.

Comment: I saw that, it is a mess.  They should change the dkms file to set the package version

Comment: @Jeremy31 Yes, indeed. However as lumiemp reports, it works.

Comment: @chili555 thank you so much. This fix works with DWA-181