# Unable to connect to wifi/tether to iphone and error installing dkms package from the bootable flashdrive for ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, drivers, wireless, dkms, additional-drivers

I am unable to connect to WiFi or tether to my iPhone for internet. Therefore unable to install any additional drivers from the software center. I did my reading on the problems and I suspect that the WiFi drivers are missing and since iOS 14 is incompatible to Ubuntu for some reason, it's not providing a tethered internet connection.

I'm very new to the Linux environment, so I am not entirely sure what I'm doing but on high-level, the idea I got was installing dkms packages from the boot-able flash drive, followed by installing additional drivers from the software center.

I've been researching and reading several posts on askUbuntu for finding a solution, for example, [this post's high rated answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/146425/how-can-i-install-and-download-drivers-without-internet?newreg=45a25bd647804702a7c04498a483beef) suggests to install dkms package from terminal commands and using GUI both. Both of them are not working for me because the terminal throws an error and GUI opens up software center for installation of dkms but gets stuck on pending.

Is there a way to solve this without the internet?

Cmd line

```
sudo dpkg -i /media/abhijeet/UBUNTU$2016_0/pool/main/d/dkms/dkms_*.deb
```

Error

```
dpkg: error processing archive /media/abhijeet/UBUNTU016_0/pool/main/d/dkms/dkms_*.deb (--install):
```

cannot access archive: No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
/media/abhijeet/UBUNTU016_0/pool/main/d/dkms/dkms_*.deb

cmd line

```
sudo dpkg -i /media/abhijeet/UBUNTU$2016_0/pool/restricted/b/bcmwl/bcmwl-kernel-source_*.deb
```

Error

```
dpkg: error processing archive /media/abhijeet/UBUNTU016_0/pool/restricted/b/bcmwl/bcmwl-kernel-source_*.deb (--install):
```

cannot access archive: No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
/media/abhijeet/UBUNTU016_0/pool/restricted/b/bcmwl/bcmwl-kernel-source_*.deb

GUI Installation screenshots
[dkms_pkg_gui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9O0cS.png)
[bcmwl_gui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RG2dj.png)

WiFi chip - Intel(R) Wireless-AC 9560 160MHz

P.S. - I'm using 16.04 for a project that's why I'm not using the latest version of it.

Comment: What does this tell us? `ls -al /media/abhijeet/UBUNTU$2016_0/pool/main/d/dkms` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1299133/how-to-get-ax500-wifi-chip-working-on-my-xps13/1299341#1299341

Comment: To @chili555's question 'ls: cannot access '/media/abhijeet/UBUNTU$2016_0/pool/main/d/dkms': No such file or directory'

Comment: Keep in the mind the EOL for 16.04 is in just a few months.

Comment: `dpkg --print-architecture` please.

Comment: I believe you have the path to the files malformed. Let's start with: `ls /media/abhijeet/`